# Can I put a caption on the lower right in Reveal.js?

Tags: css, reveal.js

I have a Reveal.js slide show that uses a lot of background images:

```
<section data-background="latimes.png">
    <small class="caption">[Some Text](http://a.link.com/whatever)</small>
    <aside class="notes">some notes</aside>
  </section>
```

And I'd like to put a caption/link for each image on the lower left-hand corner of each slide.

I tried setting a custom class

```
.reveal .caption a {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #666;
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px dashed #999;
}

.reveal .caption {
  postion: absolute; 
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to have any impact on the layout. The element inspector doesn't seem to work well with Reveal.js, which makes this hard to troubleshoot. Is there a good way to force a block of text to a corner of the screen in reveal.js?

Comment: I can set margins on `.reveal .caption` -- `margin-top: 700px; margin-right: 1000px;` that more or less works on my screen. But that seems broken.

Answer (score 6):

The reason this might be a bit tricky is because the parent nodes have some set defaults.

Set width and height to 100% in initialization of `Reveal`:

```
Reveal.initialize({
    width: "100%",
    height:"100%"
});
```

Ensure that the slide (ie. `section`) uses the whole space:

```
.full {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;  
}
```

and finally set the position of the caption:

```
.caption {
     bottom:0px;
     right:0px;
     position:absolute;
}
```

[full code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ojxLHQr8WI7np8XkQkpA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of the HTML that has the class `.reveal`? Add `position:absolute` to your selector rule. If you want the caption to sit flush at the bottom corner of each slide, it's best to set the position to `bottom:0px` instead of `top`.

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.reveal .reveal_section {
    position: relative;
}
.reveal .caption {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50px;
}
.reveal .caption a {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #666;
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 1px dashed #999;
}
</style>
<div class="reveal">
<section class="reveal_section" data-background="latimes.png">
    <small class="caption">[Some Text](http://a.link.com/whatever)</small>
    <aside class="notes">some notes</aside>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Added sample HTML and better CSS. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: You need to make parent container relative to itself, by setting its style to `position: relative`.

Comment: By "the parent container" you mean ... which? The section?

Comment: Yes, the section element. If there is a `section` element for each slide and the `section` element is the container for each slide.

Comment: I have tried this (and several other combinations of position), but have not been able to achieve the effect that the original question describes. Has anyone been able to solve this?

Comment: @rakensi So far, nope. :(

Comment: I must admit that I haven't tried very hard in the past 20 months. ;)

Comment: @rakensi If you still need to get an answer to this you could try my suggestion.

Comment: @M.T. Thank you, I will remember this the next time I use reveal.js.